# Magento: How to Edit Footer Block Titles?

Tags: blocks, language, footer, edit

I'm using a translation option, but "Quick Links" footer block title didn't translate. How can I edit this title?

Comment: > page.xml - I've changed the title from "Account" to "conta", but on the website it still appears "Account". 

`<block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links2" as="footer_links2" template="page/template/links.phtml"> <action method="setTitle"><title>Conta</title></action> </block>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say translation option do you mean you have a local folder with a language folder that holds a translate csv?  I just want to ask for my own clarification.  If not you can do it that way.

Place this in a CSV:

```
"Account","conta"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Admin Panel, select CMS > Static Blocks.
In the list, select the Footer Links block.
you can change page title for example etc to abc.